# Is it possible to change the color scheme of the Windows terminal?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, node.js

Many programs like to output certain things in blue. That's almost unreadable on a common black background. Turning off color output for the program in question is one alternative, but in X (xterm), the problem can be solved through X resources by adjusting the value of "blue color" to a slightly brighter blue. Is there a similar way to do this in Windows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

- Press `Alt-Space` (to show its menu) then select `Properties`.
- Click the `Colors` tab.
- Click each color (in the palette) you want to change, then change its Red-Green-Blue values in the `Selected Color Value` section.
- Click the color you want to use as `Screen Background`.
- Click `OK`.

Note that this affects only current "root" program. For example, you may run [Far Manager 2](http://www.farmanager.com/) using either its shortcut in `Start` menu, or run in `cmd.exe` directly (by entering `"C:\Program Files\Far2\Far.exe"` in prompt). Changes you made when running it via its shortcut have no effects when running it in `cmd.exe`, and vice versa.

So to not have to change colors in every shortcut, I just change colors for `cmd.exe`, and run any console programs from it.

Comment: Thank you!! Does anyone know WHY the default colors on Windows are so illegible. On a black background, "light blue" is too dark, and on a white back ground yellow is too light. It seems like a lose lose situation. Is it just because colors were hardly used before all the GNU stuff became more common?

Comment: I believe typing color will fix that. i.e. 'color 27' is white text on green background

Answer (score 5):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\32CpuBadBoy\Desktop>color /?
Sets the default console foreground and background colors.

COLOR [attr]

  attr        Specifies color attribute of console output
```

Color attributes are specified by TWO hex digits -- the first
corresponds to the background; the second the foreground.  Each digit
can be any of the following values:

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

If no argument is given, this command restores the color to what it was
when CMD.EXE started.  This value either comes from the current console
window, the /T command line switch or from the DefaultColor registry
value.

The COLOR command sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if an attempt is made to execute
the COLOR command with a foreground and background color that are the
same.

Example: `COLOR fc` produces light red on bright white.

Comment: Thanks! But it wasn't really what I was asking, my specific question is how do I change the shade of the color blue, not set output to blue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [this](http://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=13118) is the link you are looking for.

The following is a quote from the link.

> 1. Click Start and right click Command Prompt.
> 2. Select Properties, from the drop down context menu.
> 3. Select the Colors tab, from the resulting window.
> 4. Change the text color and background color by checking their respective boxes and then changing the color values, or selecting the
>      preset colors below.
> 5. Select Apply after choosing the new color scheme, then click OK.   NOTE: To return to default color scheme, type the following command:
>      color 08.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 10. The default colors are way too dark and I want them stronger. This is what the default colors reg definitions look like:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
"ColorTable01"=dword:00800000
"ColorTable02"=dword:00008000
"ColorTable03"=dword:00808000
"ColorTable04"=dword:00000080
"ColorTable05"=dword:00800080
"ColorTable06"=dword:00008080
"ColorTable07"=dword:00c0c0c0
"ColorTable08"=dword:00808080
"ColorTable09"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable10"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable11"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable12"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable13"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable14"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable15"=dword:00ffffff
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000007
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f5
```

To get strong colors just change all the 80 hex pairs to ff like this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
"ColorTable01"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable02"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable03"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable04"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable05"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable06"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable07"=dword:00c0c0c0
"ColorTable08"=dword:00808080
"ColorTable09"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable10"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable11"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable12"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable13"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable14"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable15"=dword:00ffffff
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000007
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f5
```

Except the gray 808080. We still want gray not white ffffff. Save this in a file ending in .reg and double click it to get strong colors. You also have to run cmd via win+r for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have released a new tool that allows loading Terminal color schemes. It supports two different formats: Ini Files and .itermcolor files from the MacOS iTerm2 application.

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/main/src/tools/ColorTool

It works on virtually any Windows version, including Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: `colortool.exe cmd-legacy` gives classic colors.  Far Manager users must run the command from Far and then open the console Properties window and click OK; or, if you want to change the colors for all console windows, use the `-b` switch.