# How to change colour scheme for batch files?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, colors

It's easy to [change the `cmd` colour scheme](https://superuser.com/a/429231/406840) or to use a tool to [customise things to an extent](https://superuser.com/a/1240275/406840).

However, all batch files seem to open with the default colour scheme with no way to change even the background. The `color` command only gives a very limited palette.

**How can you specify RGB colours for batch scripts in Windows 10?**

Comment: Why can't you use the color command?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio for the reason given. It doesn't change for batch scripts nor does it provide a 256 colour palette even if it did.